# Bad Bios checksum!

Tags: bios, прошивка

Помогите решить проблему.
Вот что пишет в Bios

```
Bad Bios checksum . Starting BIOS Recovery ...
Cheking for floppy ...
Floppy found.
Reading file "P5PL2.ROM" . Completed
Start Erasing ... |
Start Programing ... \
Please turn off your system and power on again to get system back.
```

После перезагрузки опять 25 (`Bad Bios checksum . Starting BIOS Recovery ...`) 
Прошивал с дискеты.
Материнка **ASUS P5PL2**
Bios оффициальный последний с асус сайта...
Оперативки рабочие на других компах проверялись
Переодически после простоя 10-15 мин проходит Bios до момента установки время/дата **CMOS** ( батарею также сбрасывал, перемычку переставлял)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это вообще не вопрос.

Comment: ну учитывая что мать старая возможно сдохла сама микросхема BIOS. Судя по тому что микросхема тут так просто не меняется то проще выбросить эту плату

Comment: к сожалению этот вариант отпадает, ввиду отсутствия другой материнской платы. Где то читал что дело в ОЗУ но планки в других местах работают....

Comment: Значит, придется раздобыть новую матплату, и не увлекаться излишне прошивками биоса.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить батарейку.CR2032, если что